# Increase directory size

Tags: ubuntu, partitioning, filesystems, ext4

I have installed a physical drive to my system where I'm going to save files for my application. I have mounted it at `/storage/appfiles`. Lets say in future the disk gets filled up to 100%, I will install another physical disk but how can I extend the directory `/storage/appfiles` so that I wouldn't need to modify my program's code and it will continue to work without knowing there is even another drive - is this possible?

Comment: If you initially set up your disk using [LVM](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/LVM-HOWTO/), then transparently adding a new physical disk to a volume group: `vgextend ${VOLGROUP} ${PHYSICAL_DEVICE}`

Comment: @user4556274 I'm not sure if I did that. I just connected the disk to the machine and used the command line to format and mount it.

Comment: Since this is tagged `ubuntu`, there's a good likelihood your machine was set up with `lvm` if you accepted defaults during install.  Issue `sudo lvm lvs` to list your lvm volumes.  If you get a listing, you have it.  If you get an error that `lvm` is not installed, you don't...

Comment: @user4556274 okay it appears I have lvm volumes but there are only my initial drive and the swap partition listed, the drive in question I just installed is missing - should this be the case?

Comment: Sorry I'm not putting up a full answer, the linked howto covers all.  You need to make lvm aware of the new disk with `lvm pvcreate ${PHYSICAL_DEVICE}` before adding it to your volume group.  There are many options to all the `lvm` commands; best to read the manual to ensure you get the setup you want.